# Get the canonical name instead of the distinguished name in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I would like to get the Canonical name in my report instead of the distinguished name.  That way I can sort on the OU which makes it easier to present.

To have `domain.com/users/someuser/username` easily sorted.

Here is my code

```
Import-Module activeDirectory

$output = Read-Host "'Y' for output to file or any key for output in GUI table view" -foreground Cyan
$fqdn = Read-Host "Enter FQDN domain"
$cred = Get-Credential

Write-Host "Contacting $fqdn domain..." -ForegroundColor Yellow

$domain = (get-addomain $fqdn -Credential $cred | select distinguishedName, pdcEmulator, DNSroot, DomainControllersContainer)

Write-Host "Completed. Enumerating OUs.." -ForegroundColor Yellow

$OUlist = @(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter * -Credential $cred -SearchBase $domain.distinguishedName -SearchScope Subtree -Server $domain.DNSroot)
Write-Host "Completed. Counting users..." -ForegroundColor Yellow

for ($i = 1; $i -le $oulist.Count; $i++)
    { write-progress -Activity "Collecting OUs" -Status "Finding OUs $i" -PercentComplete ($i/$OUlist.count * 100) }
$newlist = @{ }



foreach ($_objectitem in $OUlist)
{
    $getUser = Get-ADuser -Filter * -Credential $cred -SearchBase $_objectItem.DistinguishedName -SearchScope OneLevel -Server $domain.pdcEmulator | measure | select Count
    for ($i = 1; $i -le $getUser.Count; $i++)
    { write-progress -Activity "Counting users" -Status "Finding users $i in $_objectitem" -PercentComplete ($i/$getUser.count * 100) }

    $newlist.add($_objectItem.DistinguishedName, $getUser.Count)

}

if ($output -eq "Y")
{
    $newlist | ft -AutoSize | Out-File .\OUuserCount.txt


    Write-Host "All done!" -ForegroundColor yellow
}
else
{
    $newList | Out-GridView
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just need to add this parameter to get-aduser:

```
-properties canonicalname
```

And then substitute $_objectitem.distinguishedname with $getuser.canonicalname per this line:

```
$newlist.add($getuser.CanonicalName, $getUser.Count)
```

You have to use -properties as it's not a default property returned by get-aduser.

Comment: It still does not like Mark.   $newlist.add($_objectItem.Canonicalname, $getUser.Count)

Comment: Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Key cannot be null.
ERROR: Parameter name: key"
usersinou.ps1 (43, 2): ERROR: At Line: 43 char: 2
ERROR: +     $newlist.add($_objectItem.Canonicalname, $getUser.Count)

Comment: as soon as I add the  $newlist.add($_objectItem.DistinguishedName, $getUser.Count, $getUser.CanonicalName)  it fails

Comment: I do have the -properties  canonicalname in there as well

Comment: Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: '0'  Key being added: '0'"
usersinou.ps1 (41, 2): ERROR: At Line: 41 char: 2
ERROR: +     $newlist.add($getUser.Count, $getUser.CanonicalName)

Comment: I do get some output in the text file but now what we need

Comment: Name Value
---- -----
4         
0

Comment: You are getting that exception because you have the inputs the wrong way round. See the example in my answer.